# Removing part of a string in every column in pandas dataframe after a symbol

Tags: pandas

I want to remove everything after '-' in each row in one column in a pandas dataframe. I have tried str.split to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When asking for programming help, you are more likely to receive help if you show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'-.*$', '')
```

Demo:

```
In [154]: df
Out[154]:
        column
0          aaa
1  asd-bfd-asd
2  -xsdert-...
3      123-345

In [155]: df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'-.*$', '')

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
  column
0    aaa
1    asd
2
3    123
```

or using `.str.split()`:

```
In [159]: df['column'] = df['column'].str.split('-').str[0]

In [160]: df
Out[160]:
  column
0    aaa
1    asd
2
3    123
```

Comment: My personal preference would be to give the answer in terms of iloc because they didn't provide any other info 

Comment: @piRSquared, i'm not sure, i'm following you... what do you mean?

Comment: you gave a complete example which makes it moot.  But my answer would have been `df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(r'-.*$', '')`.  I wasn't suggesting anything that I thought would be an improvement.  Just sharing my preference.

Comment: @piRSquared, got it now. Thanks for sharing your personal preference! ;-)

Comment: @Claire if this answered your question, please don't forget to select it as the answer.